# Grouping elements based on criteria and eliminating duplicates

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a problem on grouping elements based on a criteria and eliminating the duplicates.

I have 2 records in XML. Document 1 and Document 2

The objective is to create a table with 3 sections. Same, Add, Delete. Elements both in the record should come in Same subsection with their quantities. Element which is not there in Doc 1 and present in Doc 2 should come into Add subsection and Elements which is there in Doc 1 and not present in Doc 2 should come into Delete subsection.

Here i am able to create 3 subsections with their total. Now my problem is to identify the similar elements based on rec_no in the same document and sum their quantities.

Here is the output table with my comments.

```
---------------------------------------------------------
Section RecNo   Desc    Doc-1 Qty   Doc-2 Qty   Total
---------------------------------------------------------
Same    111     Desc1   1           2            300
Same    444     Desc4   6           4           1000
---------------------------------------------------------
Same Total                                      1300
---------------------------------------------------------
Add     333     Desc3   3           0           300
Add     555     Desc5   5           0           500
---------------------------------------------------------
Add Total                                       800
---------------------------------------------------------
Delete  222     Desc2   0           2           200
Delete  777     Desc7   0           7           700
Delete  888     Desc8   0          10          1000
---------------------------------------------------------
Delete Total                                   1900
---------------------------------------------------------
Grand Total                                    4000
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is my XML

```
<Logia>
  <DocHeader>
        <Document>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>111</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc1</desc>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <Value>100.00</Value>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>333</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc3</desc>
                <qty>3</qty>
                <Value>300.00</Value>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>444</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc4</desc>
                <qty>6</qty>
                <Value>400.00</Value>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>555</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc5</desc>
                <qty>5</qty>
                <Value>500.00</Value>
            </Downto>
        </Document>
        <Document>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>222</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc2</desc>
                <qty>2</qty>
                <Value>200.00</Value>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>111</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc1</desc>
                <qty>2</qty>
                <Value>100.00</Value>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>444</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc4</desc>
                <qty>4</qty>
                <Value>400.00</Value>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>777</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc7</desc>
                <qty>7</qty>
                <Value>700.00</Value>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>888</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc8</desc>
                <qty>8</qty>
                <Value>800.00</Value>
            </Downto>   
            <Downto>
                <rec_no>888</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc8</desc>
                <qty>2</qty>
                <Value>800.00</Value>
            </Downto>
         </Document>
  </DocHeader>
</Logia>
```

and here is my XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="doc1" match="Document[1]/Downto" use="rec_no" />
<xsl:key name="doc2" match="Document[2]/Downto" use="rec_no" />

<xsl:template match="/Logia/DocHeader">
    <table border="1">
        <!-- header -->
        <tr>
            <th>Section</th>
            <th>RecNo</th>
            <th>Desc</th>
            <th>Doc-1 Qty</th>
            <th>Doc-2 Qty</th>   
            <th> Total</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- same -->
        <xsl:variable name="same" select="Document[1]/Downto[key('doc2', rec_no )]" />  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$same">
            <xsl:with-param name="section">Same</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:variable name="same-total" select="sum($same/Value)" />    
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">Same Total</td>
            <th><xsl:value-of select="$same-total"/></th>
        </tr>
        <!-- add -->
        <xsl:variable name="add" select="Document[1]/Downto[not(key('doc2', rec_no ))]" />  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$add">
            <xsl:with-param name="section">Add</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:variable name="add-total" select="sum($add/Value)" />  
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">Add Total</td>
            <th><xsl:value-of select="$add-total"/></th>
        </tr>
        <!-- delete -->
        <xsl:variable name="delete" select="Document[2]/Downto[not(key('doc1', rec_no ))]" />   
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$delete">
            <xsl:with-param name="section">Delete</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

        <xsl:variable name="delete-total" select="sum($delete/Value)" />    
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">Delete Total</td>
            <th><xsl:value-of select="$delete-total"/></th>
        </tr>
        <!-- grand total -->
        <tr>
            <th colspan="5">Grand Total</th>
            <th><xsl:value-of select="$same-total + $add-total + $delete-total"/></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Downto">
    <xsl:param name="section"/>
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="$section"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="rec_no"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="desc"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="qty"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="qty"/></td>  
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Value"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much to change in your code:

New key:

```
<xsl:key name="docByRecNo" match="Document/Downto" use="rec_no" />
```

Modify template that matches Downto:

```
<xsl:template match="Downto">
    <xsl:param name="section"/>
    <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('docByRecNo', rec_no)[1])">
      <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="$section"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="rec_no"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="desc"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('doc1', rec_no)/qty)"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('doc2', rec_no)/qty)"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('docByRecNo', rec_no)/Value)"/></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Here we select only those Downto records that are the first elements in group with the same rec_no (Muench grouping).